# Not able to crawl JSON from script tag using XPATH python

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

I encounter the JSON data in a script tag. I want the JSON data available in that script tag. Is there any possible way to do it.

I have tried a few tweaks regarding it but couldn't get an idea for the script tag.

html code:

```
<div id="staticid" class="a-section a-spacing-none a-padding-none">
            <script type="a-state" data-a-state="{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;turbo-checkout-page-state&quot;}">{"turboWeblab":"RCX_CHECKOUT_TURBO_DESKTOP_NONPRIME_87784","strings":{"TURBO_CHECKOUT_HEADER":"Buy now: 1byone Fake TV Simulator Anti-Burglar and Theft Deterrent with LED Light","TURBO_LOADING_TEXT":"Loading your order summary"},"inputs":{"a":"B017SJR6JS","quantity":"1","requestId":"P2JG384YYYBDM166PD5N","customItemPrice":"","oid":"dwC1O6h7HNFmAorkhv9i8nvDzUpdCtjNPCatSnP1kq1INA1KtQHHN%2F233KfCXVMuFL%2BF5rUWX5RBDz19uhFQqPVIanAuuf10V2zoV61qaytpGMPXObsZ8mHCnUFkWVEEcC7GM102R3Wk%2FB1j5q2%2FcVWrlbfu8S7n","sessionId":"260-4039899-0659318","addressId":"add-new"},"configurations":{"isSignInEnabled":true,"initiateSelector":"#buy-now-button","prefetchEnabled":true},"buttonID":"buy-now","eligibility":{"prime":false,"canOneClick":false,"preOrder":false,"stockOnHand":70,"isEligible":false,"primeShipping":true,"customerDefaults":false,"canBuyNow":true},"turboWeblabTreatment":"T1","timeout":"5000"}</script>
        </div>
```

Python code:

```
parser.xpath("//div[@id='staticid']/script")
```

This returns an empty list.

Output expected:

`{
  "turboWeblab": "RCX_CHECKOUT_TURBO_DESKTOP_NONPRIME_87784",
  "strings": {
    "TURBO_CHECKOUT_HEADER": "Buy now: 1byone Fake TV Simulator Anti-Burglar and Theft Deterrent with LED Light",
    "TURBO_LOADING_TEXT": "Loading your order summary"
  },
  "inputs": {
    "a": "B017SJR6JS",
    "quantity": "1",
    "requestId": "P2JG384YYYBDM166PD5N",
    "customItemPrice": "",
    "oid": "dwC1O6h7HNFmAorkhv9i8nvDzUpdCtjNPCatSnP1kq1INA1KtQHHN%2F233KfCXVMuFL%2BF5rUWX5RBDz19uhFQqPVIanAuuf10V2zoV61qaytpGMPXObsZ8mHCnUFkWVEEcC7GM102R3Wk%2FB1j5q2%2FcVWrlbfu8S7n",
    "sessionId": "260-4039899-0659318",
    "addressId": "add-new"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "isSignInEnabled": true,
    "initiateSelector": "#buy-now-button",
    "prefetchEnabled": true
  },
  "buttonID": "buy-now",
  "eligibility": {
    "prime": false,
    "canOneClick": false,
    "preOrder": false,
    "stockOnHand": 70,
    "isEligible": false,
    "primeShipping": true,
    "customerDefaults": false,
    "canBuyNow": true
  },
  "turboWeblabTreatment": "T1",
  "timeout": "5000"
}`

Comment: Is there a default namespace on an ancestor? (Look for xmlns="...")

Comment: @DanielHaley I dont see any default namespace. The above script is simply extracted from Amazon website. For info: [link] https://www.amazon.co.uk/1byone-Simulator-Anti-Burglar-Theft-Deterrent/dp/B017SJR6JS/ref=zg_bs_1939558031_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=2ZXV5J5WD37Z61BN5HFF

Comment: @DanielHaley parser.xpath("//div[@id=turboState'']/script")